# Mouse click on sub-menu list is failing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, onclick, submenu

I have a nested list item which i have placed under ul li html tags. I want the user to travel along the all list item through 'mouse click' event only.

Currently below code works fine, for 'mouseover' event, but not for 'mouse click' event.
I have unbinded mouseover events.

Kindly let me know how to ensure the identical behavior for click event.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>menu demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <style>
  .ui-menu {
    width: 200px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3 </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3-3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3-3-1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 3-3-1-1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3-3-2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3-4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3-5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
$("#menu").menu();
$("#menu").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave mouseover mouseout'); // we want to monitor only mouse click events

$("li:has(ul)").click(function () { 
    $(this).parent().menu();
    $(this).parent().unbind('mouseenter mouseleave mouseover mouseout'); 
});
$("li ul li:has(ul)").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().menu();
    $(this).parent().unbind('mouseenter mouseleave mouseover mouseout'); 
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have use your code and it working fine with click event. check on this http://jsfiddle.net/a58AH/ , can you provide more details

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I checked in your fiddle link. It is indeed working there perfectly. But I wonder why it is not working on browsers like chrome, IE etc. Do you have any clues why its not working on browsers?

Comment: Have you checked your browser's console for errors?

Comment: Yes. I have checked. No errors reported.

Comment: I feel this is the clear issue with library. On this http://jsfiddle.net/a58AH/ , we are using jquery (1.9.1) and jquery-ui(1.9.2) and is working fine (although there are issues as second time we need to click 3 times to open the menu item). 

But when we change the library to jquery (2.0.2 latest) and jquery-ui (1.10.3), the same code fails. The menu items disappears..

Any idea how to render this??